# Exporting and importing java project in Eclipse from Windows to Linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

I'm trying to migrate my java project from my windows machine to my linux machine. I'm using Eclipse's import/export function.

This is how the structure looks like on windows: [image: windows structure]

but when I import on the linux side the structure is completely different... and it doesn't work.

[image: linux structure]

I also tried moving the files/folders directly into the workpath. That kept the structure in place, but when trying to run the files, I only got an "does not contain a main type" error.

Exporting/Importing from windows -> windows works just fine.

Any Ideas  why this happens?

Comment: Personally, the Linux layout looks more correct in that it shows you the source packages and libraries. The windows image just shows your project like a file explorer. And you have to open the  src/main/java folder to see your files in Linux.

Comment: While I don't completely disagree, the linux versions has issues with correctly importing the project. Namely the dependencies get messed up, and can't be rebuilt on the other system.

I need some way to import a project in a way that allows it to be executed, given it was originally executable in the first place.

Comment: Does that lib folder need to be imported as a library? The `.classpath` file could have Windows paths in it that linux doesn't recognize, also

Comment: The lib folder was in the basic frame of the program given for the assignment. From what I know it's only used to eventually grade the project and has no use in my code. Regarding .classpath your idea sounds reasonable. Any clues on how to refactor it in a way that would allow usage in linux?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem now. For some reason the `Java version was set to 1.4` in the .project file... don't ask me why. That was the source of the errors in basically every file since this version doesn't support things like the diamond operator and annotations.

To do this I went into 
`Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler -> untick "Enable project specific settings"`

Probably one of the more unusual issues I had so far and I have no clue why something like this would be set as default. On a positive note the structure created by the import function was not the issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

The differences you are seeing in the view structure is that you are using a different view on Linux and Windows. On Linux it looks like you are using the standard Java view called Package Explorer that collapses packages and puts nice icons for "source" folders. The Windows screenshot looks like a Navigator View. Unfortunately is it hard to be sure as the screenshot does not show the view name.

Here is a screenshot showing both views side by side on my Linux computer for a simple project:

[image: views]